# send payments to faucetbox

Tags: bitcoin, payment-processing

I have try to do my self this code to implement the automatic send bitcoin payments to faucet box but is some errors there I need help with.
and it give me this error

```
The bitcoinrotator.publiadds.org.pt page is not working bitcoinrotator.publiadds.org.pt can not process this request for time. 500
```

```html
<?php
//custom parameters
$api_key = "my_api_key";
$userAddy = $_SESSION['user'];
require_once("faucetbox.php");
$currency = "BTC"; # or LTC or any other supported by FaucetBOX
$faucetbox = new FaucetBOX($api_key, $currency);
$users = array(
     'user_id' => clean($user_id), 
     'user_name' => clean($user_name), 
     'user_email' => clean($user_email), 
     'user_pass' => clean($user_pass), 
     'user_points' => clean($user_points), 
     'user_wallet' => clean($user_wallet)
);
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
 header("Location: index.php");
}

$selfNav = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT user_wallet, user_points FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$rowNav = mysqli_num_rows($selfNav);

$rowAssoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selfNav);

$balance = $rowAssoc['user_points'];
$wallet = $rowAssoc['user_wallet'];

//auto cashout if bal over 0.00010000
 
if($balance > 0.00010000){
     
$amount = $rowAssoc['user_points'];
     
$currency = "BTC";
  
$faucetbox = new Faucetbox($api_key, $currency);
  
$result = $faucetbox->send($wallet, $amount);
    
if($result["success"] === true){
    
$_SESSION['cashout'] = $result["html"];
    
//reset balance to zero
    
mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE `users` SET user_points = 0  WHERE user_id = " . $_SESSION['user')];
      
header('Location: ../home.php');
?>
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and provide the error message you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

well there it is its work but it stay with some bug there but now its work
the error is
Array ( [user_wallet] => 111111111111111111111111111111111111 [user_points] => 0.00000010 ) Error en balance

```html
<?php
session_start();//Session start is ALWAYS the first thing to do.
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
 header("Location: index.php"); //Sending headers its the next thing to do. Always. 
}
include_once 'dbconnect.php';


//custom parameters
$api_key = "my_api_key";
$userAddy = $_SESSION['user'];
require_once("faucetbox.php");
$currency = "BTC"; # or LTC or any other supported by FaucetBOX
$faucetbox = new FaucetBOX($api_key, $currency);
//$users = array(
//     'user_id' => clean($user_id), 
//     'user_name' => clean($user_name), 
//     'user_email' => clean($user_email), 
//     'user_pass' => clean($user_pass), 
//     'user_points' => clean($user_points), 
//     'user_wallet' => clean($user_wallet)
//);



//You are mixing mysql and mysqli, you need to choose one. Since you are on  a shared hosting, mysqli is probably
//not installed/available, so we will keep using mysql. mysqli is safer!
$selfNav = mysql_query("SELECT user_wallet, user_points FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$rowNav = mysql_num_rows($selfNav);

$rowAssoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($selfNav);

print_r($rowAssoc);

$balance = $rowAssoc['user_points'];
$wallet = $rowAssoc['user_wallet'];

//auto cashout if bal over 0.00010000
 
if($balance > 0.00010000){
     
$amount = $rowAssoc['user_points'];
     
$currency = "BTC";

  
$result = $faucetbox->send($wallet,$amount); //$amount);
    
if($result["success"] === true){
    
$_SESSION['cashout'] = $result["html"];
    
//reset balance to zero
    
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET user_points = 0  WHERE user_id = " . $_SESSION['user']);
      echo "result sucess and location go";
//header('Location: ../home.php');
}else{
 echo "Error on faucet";
 var_dump($result);
 //What happens if there is an error?
}
}else{
 echo "do not have enough credit to cash out";
 //what happens if they dont have enough balance?
}
?>
```